# What's a convenient language/framework to use to do file system operations programmatically in Ubuntu?

Tags: scripts, io

Say I want to replace a specific string in all the file-names recursively within the directory, I know how to write java code to do that, but I'm expecting there would be something that might be simpler than using Java,
Can you please provide any guide/reference for a simpler way of doing such things?

Comment: "best" is somewhat subjective (especially since you haven't given any criteria). What are you looking for exactly, beyond the standard utilities `find` + `rename` (or `find` + `mv`)?

Comment: `find + mv` does it recursively across all the files?

Comment: `find` + `rename` to ease string replacement.

Comment: The native language is python and c but we have commands for what you want. `rename.ul`  and `rename`  accept regexes to do this :) https://manpages.debian.org/testing/util-linux/rename.ul.1.en.html

Comment: I vote for `globstar` + `rename` ;-)